# What is lamda? in simple terms please.

Tags: calculus, probability

What is lamda in simple terms please i have not taken calculus, yet i need to understand it for a project i am working on.
the project i want to replicate is https://ibmathsresources.com/2019/06/19/simulating-a-football-season/
the specific part i dont understand is how to calculate lamda, i dont understand what lamda is.

Comment: "*What is lambda?*"  Whatever you want it to be.  It is a placeholder variable name, like $x$ or $a$.  What does it mean in the context of the link you provided?  It should say.

Comment: You need to provide more context.

Comment: i was just browsing for a project and this is the one i liked, i didnt understand what lamda is, for context. JMoravitz said it was a variable name, can anybody confirm please.

Comment: They model the number goals scored in a particular match-up follow a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$. The $\lambda$ is depending on the home/away condition and the teams attack / defense strength. They further model that $\lambda$ is the product of some index they generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project you linked "lamda" (which is a misspelling of lambda, i.e. the Greek letter $\lambda$) is  the parameter in a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution), in
this case the distribution of the number of goals scored in a soccer game.
They get various $\lambda$'s by making some very dubious assumptions and using some
averages, since the sample mean is an estimator of the mean of the distribution, and
the mean of the Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$ is $\lambda$.